# Идентификатор сессии в вордперсс

Tags: wordpress

Не подскажите как узнать идентификатор сессии в wordpress пробовал и `session_id()` и   `PHPSESSID` и `session.name` везде выдает  если использовать `var_damp` или `print_r` или 0 или `Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вот такая штука - [WP Session Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/faq/)

Позволяет работать с сессиями в привычном виде.

Comment: Да я уже тоже этот плагин смотрю. Но вот не пойму как id  вытянуть. неужели $wp_session['id']

Answer (score -2):

```
if ( !session_id() ) 
    session_start();

echo session_id();
```

Comment: Формально ответ так себе... На грани комментария (обычно такое удаляется), да ещё и имеет больше отношение к чистому PHP, а не движку. Вы новенький здесь, привыкайте к местным правилам.

Comment: Плохой ответ, требует пояснения и описания